# call a bash file using ssh wih PHP

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell, ssh

I have a PHP function that calls a bash file like this:

```
$res=shell_exec("sh script.sh $var1 $var2");
```

and in script.sh I wanna run another bash file using SSH that I call it like this:

```
ssh user@10.10.10.10 path-to-script/script2.sh
```

and in script2.sh it contains some commands like this: `sudo systemctl start service`

My code got to script2.sh but didn't run the command.

I think it's a problem of user rights but i don't have an idea what to change in files or add other files to make it work.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Is `script2.sh` set as executable? Perhaps try calling it like `ssh root@10.10.10.10 '/bin/bash /path-to-script/script2.sh'`

Comment: why use sudo if your login username is root?

Comment: You could try to give script2.sh to root and set the setuid bit on the script. Beware, since everyone could run these commands then. Edit: didn't see you connect as root.

Comment: because I count on using another user instead of root

Comment: @Adder how can I connect as root in my code

Comment: As others pointed out, you already connect as root. If you want to use a different user, edit your question to reflect this. In the latter case my advice is good, but not if you connect as root.

Comment: Could you try `$res=shell_exec("sh script.sh $var1 $var2 2>&1")` then `echo $res`. The `2>&1` is there to see any error messages written to stderr.

Comment: it return this message: Could not create directory '/usr/share/httpd/.ssh'. Host key verification failed

Comment: [Googeling](https://www.google.com/search?q=Could+not+create+directory+%27%2Fusr%2Fshare%2Fhttpd%2F.ssh%27.+Host+key+verification+failed) that error message should help you find the solution, if you find a solution please post it back here as an answer.